# redirect all versions of URL to https://www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

my problem is that I need all versions of my URL to redirect to https://www but I cannot figure it out.

i've tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but when i test it as:

example.com/hello

i get

https://example.com/hello

It does not add the www. Any thoughts on why?

Comment: Your rules runs fine at https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/. Have you tried removing your rules to see if the result is triggered by something else?

Comment: Have you cleared your cache? There is nothing wrong with your rules.

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Should work for ya.

Comment: when you do https://www.example.com/whatever it forwards to https://www.www.example.com/whatever (adding an extra www)